# Polynomial Curvefit - ValueError: year is out of range python

Tags: python, time-series, curve-fitting, polynomials, timeserieschart

I have a `ValueError: year is out of range python` for the below code for aiming to plot curve fit on time series.

Can anyone explain to me why I am getting this error?

```
x_values_formatted=[]

for i in x_values_edited:
    x_values_formatted.append(time.mktime(i.timetuple()))

poly = np.polyfit(x_values_formatted, y_values, 3)

polynomial = np.poly1d(poly)

xs = np.linspace(np.min(x_values_formatted), np.max(x_values_formatted), len(x_values_formatted))

y_int = polynomial(xs)

plt.plot(x_values_edited, y_values, '.')

**plt.plot(xs, y_int)**

plt.show()
```

data sample:

All inputs have a length of 1400

**x_values_formatted:**

[1420088220.0, 1420088160.0, 1420088100.0, 1420088040.0, 1420087980.0, 1420087920.0, 1420087860.0, 1420087800.0, 1420088340.0, 1420088280.0, 1420130940.0, 1420130880.0, 1420130820.0, 1420130760.0, 1420130700.0..

**y_values:**

[79.5, 79.5, 80.0, 80.25, 81.5, 81.5, 84.25, 83.0, 79.5, 77.0, 88.5, 89.0, 88.0, 89.5, 88.75, 90.0, 89.0, 89.5, 88.5, 91.0, 85.5, 80.5, 83.75, 80.25, 82.25, 80.0,

**xs:**

[  1.42006320e+09   1.42006326e+09   1.42006332e+09 ...,   1.42014942e+09
   1.42014948e+09   1.42014954e+09]

**y_int:**

[ 71.45402408  71.48215866  71.51025748 ...,  74.95840454  74.93510818
  74.91177654]

**x_values_edited**

[datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 6, 57), datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 6, 56), datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 6, 55), datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 6, 54), datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 6, 53), datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 6, 52),

Comment: Can you add some of the example data that you are using?

Comment: I have added some of the data sample. Thanks.

Comment: What is `x-values_edited` data?

Comment: I have added x_values_edited data. Thanks. @SiHa

Comment: I do not see `year`; if the error message is about it, it would be helpful if you included this part as well. Also, maybe you could provide the entire code with a reduced dataset so that we can run and fix it? Right now it is difficult to say what is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I have solved the problem